# Facebook 'Translate Open Graph Stories' not working

Tags: facebook, internationalization

I have created a couple custom open graph stories and I'm trying to translate them from English to French, but every time I try to save my translated string I get an error message in a Facebook popup saying 'Translation submission failed'.

I don't know if this problem is a Facebook bug or if there is a problem with my app configuration, but here is what I can tell you to help finding the problem.

- I am using the new facebook developer interface as you can see in the linked pictures.
- My app primary language is English (US) and I'm trying to translate to French (Canada).
- I'm an administrator of this app, but not the creator. My co worker who created the app is able to translate strings without this error message.
- He tried to add me as an 'Language managers' in the translation dashboard with my user id, but it's still not working.

I really need to get stories translated for the launch of the website. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Here is a linked picture of what happens 
[(click for picture)](http://partage.bureau300.com/2014/01/02/4e09bb681777a2c7f3f919a23038c681/full-fb.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please double check that your application's primary language is set to English (US) (Under app details) In my case, it was set to Turkish and when I was trying to translate English open graph texts to Turkish, it was giving the similar error but in Turkish. 
This change fixed my problem.

Comment: Thank you, it seemed there was a problem with facebook at that time and it got resolved in the meantime!

Comment: The problem still persists, as i cannot really change the default language to US. I am required to delete the English language as the secondary, then re-assign as primary language; however, when i try to delete my secondary language it keeps on telling me "Cannot delete your primary language". Confused!